# Mysql select combination

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have a big table with many rows like this.

```
ID / NAME    / CNT
6  / yassine / 2
5  / yassine / 9
4  / yassine / 10
3  / yassine / 12
2  / yassine / 8
1  / yassine / 3
```

what i want is to select the top 4 ID order by desc which are 6/5/4/3 then after them show the order the first **two** by id and the rest by cnt so the output is like that : 6/5/3/4.
What i have tried is

> (select * from table order by id desc limit 2) union (select * from
>   (select * from table order by id desc limit 4) order by cnt desc )

but it doesn't seem to work. Any one can help please ?
Update 1 : Output

```
 ID / NAME    / CNT
    6  / yassine / 2
    5  / yassine / 9
    3  / yassine / 12
    4  / yassine / 10
```

Comment: There is no clear way to sort your data like this.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please check update i just added the wanted output

Comment: Neither the `ID` nor `CNT` columns are ordered in your output.  Can you provide logic for how you arrived at such a result?

Comment: I'm also at loss to interpret your sorting on cnt! 9 is smaller than 10 or 12. Unless you want to order them as strings...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What i want is order the first 2 element by id so I have 6 5 and the rest by CNT SO I have 3 then 4 the final output is 6 5 3 4

Comment: @Shadow What i want is order the first 2 element by id so I have 6 5 and the rest by CNT SO I have 3 then 4 the final output is 6 5 3 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `union` to combine a query that selects the top 2 records based on id and adds a calculated field as 1, with another query that pulls 3-4 records by id adding a calculated field 0. Add an overall order by clause that uses a conditional statement based on the value of the calculated field to sort.

```
(select id, cnt, 1 as srt from yourtable order by id desc limit 2)
union
(select id, cnt, 0 as srt from yourtable order by id desc limit 2, 2)
order by srt desc, if(srt=1, id, cnt) desc
```

Comment: Your second `LIMIT` statement has a problem.

Comment: Care to explain @TimBiegeleisen?

Comment: Worked like a sharm !

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i edited limit 2,2 to the wanted range and it worked !

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the question says that the first **4** records by id needs to be ordered. The 2nd query in the union selects the 3rd and 4th records by id, so I believe it is correct. Whereas, **your** 2nd query's limit is incorrect, since it pulls all records, not just the 3rd and 4th. OP's acceptance of the query is a proof of this.

Comment: @Yassine out of curiosity,  what was the wanted range? The question mentioned 4 records.

Comment: @Shadow +1 for answering correctly the first time.  I was actually on a cell phone (and crowded bus) when I gave my first answer = high probability of messing up.  Good on you!

Comment: @Shadow I wanted to get 13 more result after the two first ids so i changed limit2,2 to 2,15 :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from t cross join 
           (select @rn := 0) params
      order by id desc
      limit 4
     ) t
order by (case when rn <= 2 then id 1 else 2 end),
         (case when rn <= 2 then id end),
         cnt;
```